# Как выполнить линковку NASM в Windows

Tags: visual-c++, ассемблер, nasm

```
global _main 
extern _printf
section .data
    msg:  db 'hello', 0
section .text
_main:
    push msg  
    call _printf
```

После трансляции командой:
nasm -f win32 1.asm
И выполнения линковки:
link /subsystem:console /entry:main 1.obj

Получаю следующую ошибку от линковщика:

1.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_printf"
1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1

Хочу использовать именно линковщик MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор не может найти внешнюю функцию _printf. Нужно в опциях линковки указать библиотеку, откуда эта функция будет загружена.